# Переобразование в двумерных массивов js

Tags: javascript

например есть такой класс, как сделать так чтобы каждые 3 элемента вошили в массив,

```
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>
<div class = "anything"></div>

let any = document.querySelectorAll(".anything")

for(let i=0;i<any.length;i++){

}
```

всмысле так

```
let x = [[any[0],any[1],any[2]],
[any[3],any[4],any[5],
[any[6],any[7],any[8]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".anything"))
const size = 3

let subarray = []; //массив в который будет выведен результат.
for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(items.length / size); i++) {
  subarray[i] = items.slice((i * size), (i * size) + size);
}
console.log(subarray);
```

```html
<div class="anything">1</div>
<div class="anything">2</div>
<div class="anything">3</div>
<div class="anything">4</div>
<div class="anything">5</div>
<div class="anything">6</div>
```